# Convergence of series with q-Pochhammer symbol

Tags: probability-theory, hypergeometric-function, q-series

I am working with the series 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\rho \beta^{j-1} \prod_{n=0}^{j-2}(1+\rho \beta^n)$$ where the empty product is assumed as usual to be 1 and $\beta, \rho \in \mathbb R^+$, with $\beta <1$. I know that the product can be replaced by the q-Pochhamer symbol, obtaining:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\rho \beta^{j-1} \left(-\rho; \beta\right)_{j-1}$$
and that the series converges since $\beta<1$. Anyone can help me in finding the best way to approximate this quantity? any pointer to related work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use define $$ F(\rho,\beta) := \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\rho \beta^{j-1} \left(-\rho; \beta\right)_{j-1}.$$ 
Then we have
$$ F(x,q) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n q^{n(n-1)/2}/(q;q)_n = -1 +\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + xq^n).$$
This is the generating function of OEIS sequence [A008289](http://oeis.org/A008289) where $|q|<1$ for convergence.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will study the properties of sequence A008289. I am really new to this stuff. For example it is unclear why $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n q)$ should converge if $0<q<1$ and $x>1$ (since the assumptions are $\rho>0$ and $0<\beta<1$). Anyway I will try to follow the Math.

Comment: I made typos in the infinite product. Sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. I understood how you derived the last equality but not the reason why:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \rho\beta^{j-1}(-\rho;\beta)_{j-1}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\rho^j \beta^{j(j-1)/2}}{(\beta;\beta)_j}
$$
However, as I told before I am new to this, so I am working to solve it.

Comment: You might find this identity interesting: $-1+(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\dots=a(1)+b(1+a)+c(1+a)(1+b)+\cdots.$

Comment: The reason for the equality relates to interpretation as to counting partitions of integers in two ways as noted in A008289.

Comment: This is a very fascinating topic. The problem came up when studying a particular queueing system, the series is required to compute the probability of the empty queue! By the way in A008289 I think you wrote $\beta^{j(j+1)/2}$ instead of $\beta^{j(j-1)/2}$.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for my typo. In A008289 $\sum_{n>0} Q(n,k) x^n y^k = -1 + \prod_{n>0} (1+y x^n)$ where the product is for $n>0$.